# How do i make div go under another div making columns

Tags: html, css

How do i make div go under another div making columns with css no js. please!

i got just one container with 100% width and many divs trying to make go one under another making columns i would like to keep the order of the code...

Comment: thank you, i need the divs to align under each other but when the container get full i need them to make another column

Comment: Check out the CSS 'z-index' attribute. It's essentially a depth control for elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to have columns within a DIV, you can simply do something like:

```
div {
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: thank you i need them t o make order columns, like lists but making automatic columns when need it

Comment: It sounds to me like you are looking for: column-count. Set column count on your div to be the number of columns you want within that particular div, and it should do the trick.